# What type of object is manipulated by logging filters?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently taking a closer look at [Django logging filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#filters).
In one of their examples, they define this filtering method:

```
from django.http import UnreadablePostError

def skip_unreadable_post(record):
    if record.exc_info:
        exc_type, exc_value = record.exc_info[:2]
        if isinstance(exc_value, UnreadablePostError):
            return False
    return True
```

I'd like to go further with filtering, but I need to know what's contained in this `record` parameter, so I can manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a [LogRecord](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects).  This can be found by systematically printing the said `record` attribute, like so:

```
def print_record(record):
    print '>>> %s' % type(record)
    return True


LOGGING = {
    [...]
    'filters': {
        'print_record': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': print_record,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['print_record'],
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```